# Preserve styled-components displayName in esbuild

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, vite, esbuild

I have a monorepo setup with Vite as a build system. I'm using styled-components for styles and want to preserve `displayName` for React components during development. I enabled `displayName` in `build` section of Vite config. Other monorepo package (listed as a dependency) is also using styled-components, but root `displayName` configuration seems to be ignored for it.

As I understand from [this section](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html), Vite uses esbuild to pre-build dependencies. Hence, my settings seem to be ignored in this step. The resulting tree looks like this (see minified CSS names in nested nodes):

[image]

If I understand correctly, I have to tweak esbuild settings via Vite's `optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions`, but I currently was not able to find a way to do it for styled-components.

Comment: Having same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Christopher unfortunately no. I gave up =P

Answer (score 0):

I solved this after a long battle! Hopefully this helps. I am using Vite, React.js, and styled-components. No SSR or anything fancy.

The solution is to walk back the package version. That older version has code that should work with your setup. Then just import from a sub folder of the new package, and drop in a babel plugin.

[image]

1. You need to delete your styled-components repo from node_modules.
2. Then go into package.json and change the styled-components version number. For me, the version that ended up working was `5.3.0`. You need the version to have a folder called macro.
3. Then run `npm i` to install the new version of styled components.
4. Now from each of your components, instead of importing like this -> `import styled from 'styled-components'`; you need to do this -> `import styled from 'styled-components/macro';`. You are telling the file it needs to load from the sub folder. This sub folder allows for readable names.
5. Now make sure you have the correct loader in your vite.config.js file. It is called `'vite-plugin-babel-macros'`. The version should be `1.0.5`. Some other versions don't work. This will extend vote’s bundling ability to read/handle code in the macros folder. My config looks like this.

`import { defineConfig } from 'vite';`

`import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';`

`import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros";`

```
export default defineConfig({
    define: {
        'process.env': {},
    },
    plugins: [
        macrosPlugin(),
      react()
    ]
  })
```

6. Finally you need to run `npm i vite-plugin-babel-macros` so that there is code for the plugin in your node_modules.
7. Restart Vite so the new bundle changes are picked up and everything should work!

(If you are creating newer projects with swc, take a look at [this](https://github.com/unyo/vite-swc-styled-components-legacy/tree/main). This link works for my newer setups where I don't have the same constraints. It was adapted by the author from [this](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components/issues/350).)